# Using after_stat or ..prop.. breaks a bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I can't for the life of me figure out why this doesn't work. I tried the old ..prop.. and I see the same error. I'm not sure what's going on. Anyone else?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork) 
x <- rbinom(n = 1000, size = 5, prob = 0.3) #simulate a random sample
plotdatax = tibble(xvar = as.factor(x))
p1 <- ggplot(data = plotdatax) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = xvar))

p2 <- ggplot(data = plotdatax) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = xvar, y = after_stat(prop)))
p1+p2
```

[image: resulting graph]

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue using `ggplot2 3.4.4`. Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, after quite a while of tinkering, it's the as.factor() bit. That is, this works fine. Hopefully, I save someone about an hour here...

```
plotdatax = tibble(xvar = x)
p1 <- ggplot(data = plotdatax) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = xvar))

p2 <- ggplot(data = plotdatax) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = xvar, y = after_stat(prop)))
p1+p2
```